# C: Accessing or trying to alter a passed variable in a particular segment of a function involving message queues stops the process

Tags: c, reference, ipc, message-queue

I am trying to get processes to communicate and form groups through message queues.
In this case, a process forks into a number of children that communicate.
What bugs me, actually, is the fact that when entering a particular function that uses both the message queue and some variables i need to change with it, accessing the dereferencered values seems to stop the execution of the process (and the others too since it doesn't "release" the semaphore they share) until the parent process stops its children and starts doing something else.

`struct msgbuf {
    long mtype;
    int mtext[2];
};`

This is the msgbuf i'm using.

`int checkMsg(int msgid, struct msgbuf messaggio, int voto, int * partner, int * took, int * rejects, int *pending){
    ...
    while(msgrcv(msgid, &messaggio, sizeof(messaggio), getpid(), IPC_NOWAIT) != -1){
        if(messaggio.mtext[0]==1){
            printf("%s\n", strerror(errno)); // this is shown in the terminal
            printf("%d\n", * partner); // this is not shown, blocking the execution
            * partner = messaggio.mtext[1];
            * took = 1;
            * pending = *pending - 1;
            refuseInvites(msgid, messaggio);
            return 1;
        }
    ...
    }
...
}`

And this is the problematic piece of code.

I tried changing the second printf to output *took and it does, but then the execution stops again (i presume the moment *partner is taken into consideration). the value of partner should be set to 0 before entering the function and messaggio.mtext[1] is a process ID. 
I expect the function to not stop and returning successfully, mantaining the consistency of the data.

EDIT : The call to checkMsg() is this one:
`taken = checkMsg(msgid, messaggio, voto, &partner, &took, &rejects, &pending);`

partner, took, rejects and pending are set to 0 before the forking

EDIT 2: all the variables are of type int and the signature of the checkMsg is included in a header before the program starts.

Comment: can you show the call of _checkMsg_ ? If to dereference these pointers stops (_crashes_) the execution that means at least one of them does not point to something valid

Comment: Please [edit] to make a [mcve]. Use formatting to improve readability. https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: @ButtonMasher these vars have a right type and the signature of _checkMsg_ is known when calling it ? Can you execute your program under _valgrind_ ?

Comment: I executed the program under valgrind but it outputs a lot of data, what should I look for, exactly?